# Dictionary Object in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm new to coding and I've started working on a task in c#. I've to develop a code to get file information, like file type, file size, owner name for a given directory path input.

Now, to save time, I thought of building a dictionary in which I'll store all the SID and corresponding Owner information. And the code won't loop through to get owner name each time by converting SID for each file, instead it will get the SID for that file and map it to it's owner using the built dictionary. This dictionary will be built once and will be updated if any new owner joins.
Does anyone know how to create a dictionary that can be used separately.

Here's the code I'm working on --

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
//using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem;
// Alpha is external library used to allow long paths.

namespace Get_SID_Owner_Info
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the Directory Path --  ");
            string foldr = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter the result path location e.g. D:\\Nolder\\Outfile.csv --  ");
            string outfile = Console.ReadLine();

            //string foldr = "D:\\Ansys_Training";
            //string outfile = "D:\\Get_SID_Owner.csv";

            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            int[] index = new int[1000000];

            int i;
            i = 0;

            IdentityReference[] SID_store   = new IdentityReference[1000000];
            IdentityReference[] Owner_store = new IdentityReference[1000000];

            if (File.Exists(outfile))
            {
                File.Delete(outfile);
            }

            // Create a new file     
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(outfile))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0},{1}", "SID", "Owner Name");

                string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(foldr);
                DirectoryInfo tempWithoutMac = new DirectoryInfo(foldr);

                foreach (FileInfo fi in tempWithoutMac.GetFiles())
                {
                 // SID --
                    FileSecurity fs = File.GetAccessControl(fi.FullName);
                    IdentityReference SID = fs.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
                 // Owner -- 
                    IdentityReference Owner = SID.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

                    SID_store[i] = SID;
                    Owner_store[i] = Owner;

                    i = i + 1;
                }


                foreach (string d in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(foldr, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    tempWithoutMac = new DirectoryInfo(d);

                    foreach (FileInfo fi in tempWithoutMac.GetFiles())
                    {
                        // SID --
                        FileSecurity fs = File.GetAccessControl(fi.FullName);
                        IdentityReference SID = fs.GetOwner(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
                        // Owner -- 
                        IdentityReference Owner = SID.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));

                        SID_store[i] = SID;
                        Owner_store[i] = Owner;

                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }
                IdentityReference[] SID_store2 = new IdentityReference[i];
                IdentityReference[] Owner_store2 = new IdentityReference[i];

                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
                {
                    SID_store2[j]   = SID_store[j];
                    Owner_store2[j] = Owner_store[j];
                }

                var SID_Unique   = SID_store2.Distinct().ToList();            // Contains Unique SID's for the given directory --
                var Owner_Unique = Owner_store2.Distinct().ToList();

                Dictionary<IdentityReference, IdentityReference> SID_Owner_Data = new Dictionary<IdentityReference, IdentityReference>();

                for (int j = 0; j < SID_Unique.Count; j++)                  // SID to Owner conversion for the Unique SID's --
                {
                    SID_Owner_Data.Add(SID_Unique[j], Owner_Unique[j]);

                    Console.WriteLine(SID_Unique[j]);
                    Console.WriteLine(Owner_Unique[j]);
                }

                Console.WriteLine(SID_Unique.Count);

                for (int k = 0; k < SID_Unique.Count; k++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("{0},{1}", SID_Unique[k], Owner_Unique[k]);
                }
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Execution Time: {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share some code and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: You can create one class like owner information  and then create  a dictionary with sid as key and value will be that class object details corresponding to sid

Comment: I want to create a dictionary using this code that can be used later.

Comment: i tried around how to improve this, and yes `SID.Translate` is the most expensive part (75%), if you have a FileHandle you can get the SID super fast by pinvoke `GetSecurityInfo()` (cost is 500ms for 100_000 calls) instead of using `GetAccessControl, GetOwner`

Comment: Can you share more information on using pinvoke to get SID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to resolve an SID to its owner, but through a caching mechanism so that each SID is resolved only once. This is trivial to do with a ConcurrentDictionary and [`GetOrAdd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.getoradd?view=netframework-4.8).

```
ConcurrentDictionary<IdentityReference,IdentityReference> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<IdentityReference,IdentityReference>();

IdentityReference GetTranslationWithCache(IdentityReference SID)
{
    return _cache.GetOrAdd( SID, () => SID.Translate(typeof(NTAccount));
}
```

In this example. `GetOrAdd` will search the cache for the SID and return the corresponding translation if it is found. If it is not found, the key is added to the dictionary and the delegate (`() => SID.Translate`) is called in order to populate its value. This makes it good for use as a cache. As a bonus, your dictionary is thread-safe, so you can populate it from multiple threads to improve performance, and still guarantee that the calls to `Translate` will only happen once per SID.

Comment: Thank you, this will work. But actually to further reduce time, we're thinking of doing it once and use it every time we need it.

i.e. to create a generic dictionary which will contain all the SID-Owner key\pairs. And so, we don't have to find out the Owner name from SID at all, we can simply refer the dictionary to get that. 
-------
Of course in case a new owner comes, we have to update the dictionary from time to time.

Comment: i think this is a good solution, because it will only do one lookup for each SID, which should only be a few.

Comment: I would advise against a persistent cache as there are security and operational concerns. If you are having performance issues, work on improving the performance of your API calls (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7967166/2791540)).